# Why python raise a runtime error while i run numpy.percentile for equalization by scikit-image?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, runtime-error, scikit-image

I take the equalization code from [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.9.x/auto_examples/plot_equalize.html)

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology
from skimage import color
from skimage import io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import data, img_as_float
from skimage import exposure


img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread(path))

# Contrast stretching
p2 = np.percentile(img, 2)
p98 = np.percentile(img, 98)
#img_rescale = exposure.rescale_intensity(img, in_range=(p2, p98))
img_rescale = exposure.rescale_intensity(img, out_range=(0, 255))

# Equalization
img_eq = exposure.equalize_hist(img)

# Adaptive Equalization
img_adapteq = exposure.equalize_adapthist(img, clip_limit=0.03)
```

and when i use this kind of image:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzBWU.jpg)

i got this error:

```
Run time Error!
```

python stopped and respond:

```
this application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way!
```

at this line:

```
p2 = np.percentile(img, 2)
```

Comment: I think it is the file size, if i skip the images with a >>2MB size i can run my script, but after 65 files (<<2MB) python stop running again!

Comment: might be a bug in numpy, which version are you using? try updating to the latest version. Also `p2, p98 = np.percentile(img, (2, 98))` is faster than two percentile calls.

Comment: But with other images works fine!

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434258/why-python-raise-a-runtime-error-only-with-certain-images i make a new question with much more information. The thinks are a little bit change!