# Why python raise a runtime error only with certain images?

Tags: python, image-processing, runtime-error, mahotas

It is the third question i do in stackoverflow about that because every time i got some changes in the way python raise runtime erro.

Previous questions were: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339555/how-can-i-solve-a-memory-error-of-python-scikit-image-function-color-rgb2gray#) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333700/why-python-raise-a-runtime-error-while-i-run-numpy-percentile-for-equalization-b).
In the first question i think was a matter of memory because i anylized many images, in the second case the runtime error happen at this line

```
p2 = numpy.percentile(img, 2)
```

and i think was a numpy module problem.

but now i the runtime error happens here:

```
imgbnbin = mh.morph.dilate(gray, disk7)
```

At mahotas function dilate.

the only three image i have among 90 images are this:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

and these are 2 sample images where the code works fine:

[image: imageright1]

[image: imageright2]

Below, there is the code of my function skelfeatures where i got the runtime error:

```
import os
import glob
import scipy
import numpy as np
import pymorph as pm

import pylab as plb
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
import mahotas as mh
from skimage import morphology
from skimage import io
from math import sqrt

from skimage import data, img_as_float
from skimage import exposure
from skimage import color
from skimage import io, filter
from skimage.morphology import erosion, dilation, opening, closing, white_tophat
from skimage.morphology import black_tophat, skeletonize, convex_hull_image
from skimage.morphology import disk

def plot_img_and_hist(img, axes, bins=256):
    """Plot an image along with its histogram and cumulative histogram.

    """
    img = img_as_float(img)
    ax_img, ax_hist = axes
    ax_cdf = ax_hist.twinx()

    # Display image
    ax_img.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    ax_img.set_axis_off()

    # Display histogram
    ax_hist.hist(img.ravel(), bins=bins, histtype='step', color='black')
    ax_hist.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='scientific', scilimits=(0, 0))
    ax_hist.set_xlabel('Pixel intensity')
    ax_hist.set_xlim(0, 1)
    ax_hist.set_yticks([])

    # Display cumulative distribution
    img_cdf, bins = exposure.cumulative_distribution(img, bins)
    ax_cdf.plot(bins, img_cdf, 'r')
    ax_cdf.set_yticks([])

    return ax_img, ax_hist, ax_cdf
import urllib, cStringIO
listarough = list()  
def skelfeatures(path):
    import copy

    if (path[0] == "h"):
        #URL
        req = urllib.urlopen(path)  #cv2.imdecode(arr,0) # load as grayscale
        arr = np.asarray(bytearray(req.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
        gray = cv2.imdecode(arr,0) # 'load it as it is'

        #cv2.imshow('lalala',gray)
        #if cv2.waitKey() & 0xff == 27: quit()
    else:
        #local path
        print("prima di cv2imread")
        gray = cv2.imread(path,0)

    stampac = "no"

    originale = copy.copy(gray)     
    oshape = list(gray.shape)
    if (oshape[0] <= 140):
        #print(oshape[0]/100)
        ow =  int ((oshape[0]/100 )*2.5 )
        oh =  int ((oshape[0]/100 )*2.5 )
        #print("ow ",ow)    
    elif (oshape[0] <= 300):
        #print(oshape[0]/100)
        ow =  int ((oshape[0]/100 )*3.5 )
        oh =  int ((oshape[0]/100 )*3.5 )
        #print("ow ",ow)
    else:
        ow =  int ((oshape[0]/100 )*7 )
        oh =  int ((oshape[0]/100 )*7 )
    owclose = ow * 2

    element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(ow,oh)) 
    graydilate = cv2.erode(gray, element) #imgbnbin
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) 
    gray = thresh

    proxMax = int((oshape[0]/100 )*22) 
    proxMin = int((oshape[0]/100 )*19)
    proxGE = 5
    proxGEmin = 2

    oshape = list(gray.shape)

    if (oshape[0] <= 140):
        #print(oshape[0]/100)
        ow =  int ((oshape[0]/100 )*2.5 )
        oh =  int ((oshape[0]/100 )*2.5 )
        #print("ow ",ow)    
    elif (oshape[0] <= 300):
        #print(oshape[0]/100)
        ow =  int ((oshape[0]/100 )*3.5 )
        oh =  int ((oshape[0]/100 )*3.5 )
        #print("ow ",ow)
    else:
        ow =  int ((oshape[0]/100 )*7 )
        oh =  int ((oshape[0]/100 )*7 )
    #print(ow)
    owclose = ow * 2

    disko = pm.sedisk(0.2)
    imgbnbin7 = gray

    ############################################################
    #                    OPEN ImAGE PATH
    ############################################################

    print("mahotas")     
    img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread(path))
    print(type(img))
    print("FINE ioimread")
    from skimage import exposure
    #print dir(exposure)

    # Contrast stretching
    ###########################################################################
    #       THE FIRST TIME WHERE I GOT RUNTIME ERROR, the following line
    ###########################################################################
    p2 = np.percentile(img, 2)
    p98 = np.percentile(img, 98)
    img_rescale = exposure.rescale_intensity(img, out_range=(0, 1))


    # Equalization
    img_eq = exposure.equalize_hist(img)

    # Adaptive Equalization
    img_adapteq = exposure.equalize_adapthist(img, clip_limit=0.03)

    # Display results
    '''f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(8, 4))

    ax_img, ax_hist, ax_cdf = plot_img_and_hist(img, axes[:, 0])
    ax_img.set_title('Low contrast image')

    y_min, y_max = ax_hist.get_ylim()
    ax_hist.set_ylabel('Number of pixels')
    ax_hist.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, y_max, 5))

    ax_img, ax_hist, ax_cdf = plot_img_and_hist(img_rescale, axes[:, 1])
    ax_img.set_title('Contrast stretching')

    ax_img, ax_hist, ax_cdf = plot_img_and_hist(img_eq, axes[:, 2])
    ax_img.set_title('Histogram equalization')

    ax_img, ax_hist, ax_cdf = plot_img_and_hist(img_adapteq, axes[:, 3])
    ax_img.set_title('Adaptive equalization')

    ax_cdf.set_ylabel('Fraction of total intensity')
    ax_cdf.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, 1, 5))

    #prevent overlap of y-axis labels
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4)
    plt.show()'''

    if ( stampac =="no" ):        
        plt.gray()
        plt.subplot(121)
        plt.title("dopo histo")
        plt.imshow(img)
        plt.show()

    binimg = img_adapteq

    if ( stampac =="no" ):        
        plt.gray()
        plt.subplot(121)
        plt.title("dopo conversione")
        plt.imshow(binimg)
        plt.show()

    binimgafter = copy.copy(binimg)
    threshold = filter.threshold_otsu(img_rescale)
    gray =( img_rescale< threshold)

    if ( stampac =="si" ):        
        plt.gray()
        plt.subplot(121)
        plt.title("dopo otsu")
        plt.imshow(gray)
        plt.show()

    shape = gray.shape
    w = 0
    if (shape[0] > shape[1]):
        shape = shape[0]
    else:
        shape = shape[1]

    if (shape < 100):
        w =  int((shape/100 )*1.5)
    elif(shape > 100 and shape <420):
        w =  int((shape/100 )*2.5)
    else:
        w = int((shape/100)*4)
    disk7 = pm.sedisk(w)
    print("bau2")    

    imgbnbin = mh.morph.dilate(gray, disk7)
    if ( stampac =="no" ):   #2     
        plt.gray()
        plt.subplot(121)
        plt.title("dopo dilate prima di close")
        plt.imshow(imgbnbin)
        plt.show()

    ########################################################
    #RUNTIME ERROR HER. After that python does not show bau3
   ###########################################################
    print("bau3")  
    imgbnbin = mh.morph.close(imgbnbin, disko) 
    if ( stampac =="no" ):   #2     
        plt.gray()
        plt.subplot(121)
        plt.title("dopo close prima di skeletonize")
        plt.imshow(imgbnbin)
        plt.show()

    out = morphology.skeletonize(imgbnbin>0)
    # the function continue...
path = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzBWU.jpg"
```

Comment: Can you show the traceback?

Comment: @postgres Thank you for telling us the type of error that occurred, but we can provide a better solution if you give us the full trace-back as a `RuntimeError` can be caused by a variety of different things.

Comment: i cannot, it stopped showing only a new window with this message: "this application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way!" 'm not an expert if there is another way to show the traceback anyway, i'll do it.

Comment: Author of mahotas here. This may be a bug in the package, but it's not clear exactly what you're doing. Can you isolate the images ``gray`` and ``disk7`` which are used in  ``mh.morph.dilate(gray, disk7)`` and cause the problem?

Comment: i comment that line and add imgbnbin = gray python stop running anyway. It open a new window: "Python stop working"

Comment: I found another image that give me the same problem: http://i.imgur.com/Voz8KqE.jpg

Comment: How can i avoid the runtime error in a way that python terminate the script rightly?